# using RestSharp to create a specific request type

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, restsharp

We are using RestSharp to upload a base64 encoded file.  The API requires a request format that looks like the following, but we are unable to produce this format using RestSharp.  I think there must be a way?

**FORMAT 1**

```
POST https://www.myapiurl.com/api/v1/add HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Length: 522

----------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

7926456167
----------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

test2.txt
----------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"


----------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"

dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=
----------------------------330780699366863579549053--
```

Using RestSharp, we are only able to create a request that looks like...

**FORMAT 2**

```
POST https://www.myapiurl.com/api/v1/add HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------330780699366863579549053
Content-Length: 83

id=7926456167&filename=SQLSearch.exe&description=&attachment=dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=
```

For the API we are hitting, this works fine unless the "attachment" parameter is a larger file.  We can manually compose/submit a request for larger files if we use FORMAT 1.  FORMAT 2 fails, but that is all we can get out of RestSharp.

Here is the code we are using.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://myapiurl.com/api/v1/add");
var restRequest = new RestRequest(request, Method.POST);
restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------330780699366863579549053");
restRequest.AddParameter("id", "7926456167", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
restRequest.AddParameter("filename", "test2.txt", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
restRequest.AddParameter("description", "", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
restRequest.AddParameter("attachment", "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

How is this code changed to produce a request in FORMAT 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RestSharp` can build a proper `multipart/form-data` request automatically, so you don't need to specify `Content-Type` header manually and you can remove `multipart/form-data` and `ParameterType.RequestBody` from parameters. Then you just need to set `AlwaysMultipartFormData` property to `true` so it will generate proper headers and body for you

```
var client = new RestClient("http://myapiurl.com/api/v1/add");
var restRequest = new RestRequest(request, Method.POST);
restRequest.AddParameter("id", "7926456167");
restRequest.AddParameter("filename", "test2.txt");
restRequest.AddParameter("description", "");
restRequest.AddParameter("attachment", "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=");
restRequest.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
```